# subtracting/adding values for MySQL columns in INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume I have `transfers` and `bank_accounts` table. I wish to run the following query:

```
INSERT INTO transfers SET amount = 1234, sender_account = 323, receiver_account = 324;
```

I want to modify my query thus, that it will increase `receiver_account` balance by the transfer amount and decrease the balance of the `sender_account`. Is this possible in MySQL?

**EDIT**
 `sender_account` and `receiver_account` columns are foreign keys of `bank_accounts`.

Comment: Use triggers! (To make sure no one ever misses to update both tables.)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this. Second one is my favorite and less prone to errors.

1) if this is running in the same function/class (PHP, java, etc...) then the values of amount, sender_account, receiver_account are all available to you as variables then you can build you MySQL using the standard update statement:

```
UPDATE bank_accounts SET balance = balance + amount WHERE account_id = receiverAccount
UPDATE bank_accounts SET balance = balance - amount WHERE account_id = senderAccount
```

account_id being the primary key of the bank_accounts table and receiverAccount/senderAccount are the variable that contain the values.

2) If the values are not available to you in the same function, then you can resort to using triggers.

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateAccounts
AFTER INSERT ON transfers
BEGIN
UPDATE bank_accounts SET balance = balance + NEW.amount WHERE account_id = NEW.receiver_account
UPDATE bank_accounts SET balance = balance - NEW.amount WHERE account_id = NEW.senderAccount
END;
```

Triggers are helpful when there are multiple updates that should happen to different tables and you do not want to miss any of them. Really handy for projects like banking.
You can read more about triggers and how they are used here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

Comment: You have to enclose the `UPDATE` queries (and the original `INSERT` query, if possible) into a [`TRANSACTION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html).

Answer (score 0):

Without triggers, you cannot INSERT and UPDATE different tables only with a query.